# Slow UPDATE, can't work out why

Tags: mysql, database, join

I have a slow UPDATE statement and can't work out why

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE ttShifts
(ShiftId int NOT NULL, ttdtAdded datetime not null, ttdtBookingStart DATETIME NOT NULL, ttHoursNeeded int not null, szHidden varchar(255),
 PRIMARY KEY (ShiftID))
 AS
 (select shiftId, dtAdded as ttdtAdded, dtBookingStart as ttdtBookingStart, HoursNeeded as ttHoursNeeded from shifts where shifts.lStatus=0);

 update ttShifts set szHidden='x' where szHidden is NULL and ShiftId in (select shiftid from shifts,practices where shifts.PracticeId=practices.PracticeId and shifts.iBranch = practices.iBranch and practices.Healthboard not in (select Locname from userlocationprefs where iUser=82 and Level=0 and fAcceptWork=true))

166 rows affected. (Query took 0.2899 seconds.)
```

EXPLAIN:

```
  1 PRIMARY ttShifts    index       PRIMARY 4       297 Using where 
  2 DEPENDENT SUBQUERY  shifts  eq_ref  PRIMARY PRIMARY 4   func    1       
  2 DEPENDENT SUBQUERY  practices   ALL PRIMARY             636 Using where; Using join buffer (flat, BNL join) 
  3 MATERIALIZED    userlocationprefs   ref PRIMARY PRIMARY 8   const,const 3   Using where
```

OK, so let's try switching this to use a join to eliminate the dependent subqueries

```
update ttShifts join shifts on (ttShifts.ShiftID=shifts.shiftId) join practices on (shifts.practiceId=practices.PracticeId and shifts.iBranch=practices.iBranch) set szHidden='x' where szHidden is NULL and practices.Healthboard not in (select Locname from userlocationprefs where iUser=82 and Level=0 and fAcceptWork=true);

166 rows affected. (Query took 0.4009 seconds.)
```

Right, so that takes *longer*

EXPLAIN:

```
1   PRIMARY ttShifts    ALL PRIMARY             297 Using where 
1   PRIMARY shifts  eq_ref  PRIMARY PRIMARY 4   ttShifts.shiftId    1       
1   PRIMARY practices   ALL                 636 Using where 
2   MATERIALIZED    userlocationprefs   ref PRIMARY PRIMARY 8   const,const 3   Using where
```

OK, so it must be the MATERIALIZED bit it's not doing efficiently for some reason, let's try swapping that to a straight equality check just as a test.

```
update ttShifts join shifts on (ttShifts.ShiftID=shifts.shiftId) join practices on (shifts.practiceId=practices.PracticeId and shifts.iBranch=practices.iBranch) set szHidden='x' where szHidden is NULL and practices.Healthboard!='X'
```

0.3493 seconds.

OK, not that then.

If I eliminate the update and make it a select...

```
select * from ttShifts join shifts on (ttShifts.ShiftID=shifts.shiftId) join practices on (shifts.practiceId=practices.PracticeId and shifts.iBranch=practices.iBranch) where szHidden is NULL and practices.Healthboard not in (select Locname from userlocationprefs where iUser=82 and Level=0 and fAcceptWork=true)

(166 rows, Query took 0.0159 seconds.)
```

So why is the UPDATE so bloody slow, and what can I do to speed it up?

Comment: When you use join it wil slower your query in your case your using join in the update query. If your updating rows you could consider to use index. Are you already using index ? if not check if this will work for you

Comment: Yes, it is updating the temporary table based on ShiftID and that's a primary key of the temporary table.  All the other comparisons have an index too.

Comment: Please give DDL for all tables. Obviously constraints & indexes are important for this question. But any code question is are off-topic without a [mcve]. Please format your code & tables so they can be read.

Comment: Why do you join shifts with ttShifts? Their join on a key is just ttShifts.

Answer (score 0):

Your first `EXPLAIN` output tells us that it needs to process 297*1*636*3 rows = 566,676 rows. So yes it will take a moment to process. It is similar to second EXPLAIN output.

If I were you, I will try to focus on entry marked as `ALL` as it represent table scan operation.

Also, `IN` work best with list of constant value not sub query as they cause index to be useless. Try to remove sub query with constant value if possible.

The second EXPLAIN even worse because there are two table scan without index available to use.

Third UPDATE there is no EXPLAIN output, but again I think because number of rows to process is still high because you use column with low cardinality (`not null`) and `healthBoard !='x'` as filtering criteria WHERE clause.

Your last query try to compare speed of SELECT vs UPDATE. Well, UPDATE is more expensive because it has to search the matching row, write the value, write the the index.

From what I see, most of your problem is due low cardinality column is used as filtering criteria.

Comment: There is something going on with UPDATE vs SELECT, for such a difference in speed - 0.0159s for SELECT vs 0.2899s for an UPDATE.  I went Googling and found some suggestions that the optimiser doesn't work well with single table updates (http://mysqlserverteam.com/multi-table-trick/).  Applying that - see below - speeds up things to 0.1799s.

Comment: update (select 1) as dummy, ttShifts set szHidden='x' where szHidden is NULL and ShiftId in (select shiftid from shifts,practices where shifts.PracticeId=practices.PracticeId and shifts.iBranch = practices.iBranch and practices.Healthboard not in (select Locname from userlocationprefs where iUser=82 and Level=0 and fAcceptWork=true))

Comment: The JOIN method is still slower, though.  0.18s is acceptable for the query, but I'm going to keep picking at it.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone else who runs across this, it seems the issue is with how the optimiser handles IN with update vs select.  I refactored things so the user viewing preferences was set in a separate table testuserchosenpractices, and then I could join it.

I can't explain the difference in speed between UPDATE and SELECT originally (as SELECT was perfectly tolerable) but with the replacement the UPDATE is faster than the original SELECT was!

update (select 1) as dummy, ttShifts set szHidden='x' where szHidden is NULL and ShiftId in (select shiftid from shifts join practices on (shifts.PracticeId=practices.PracticeId and shifts.iBranch = practices.iBranch) join testuserchosenpractices on (shifts.practiceid=testuserchosenpractices.practiceid and shifts.ibranch=testuserchosenpractices.ibranch and testuserchosenpractices.iUser=82) and szReason!='')

166 rows affected. (Query took 0.0066 seconds.)